# Título no MasterDetail - Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-forms

Preciso ter título "Tela Principal" num no MasterDetail que tenho, é possível?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
              x:Class="FoodSuppy.Principal"
              xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FoodSuppy;assembly=FoodSuppy"
              NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">
<!-- Sair -->
<MasterDetailPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Sair"
                 Clicked="Sair_Clicked"/>
</MasterDetailPage.ToolbarItems> 

<!-- Menu -->
<MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <ContentPage Title="Menu" 
                 Icon="menu.png">
        <StackLayout>
            <Button Text="Pag Principal" 
                    Clicked="btnPagina1_Clicked"/>
            <Button Text="Alterar cadastro" 
                    Clicked="btnPagina2_Clicked"/>
            <Button Text="Ajuda" 
                    Clicked="btnAjuda_Clicked"/>
            <Button Text="Sobre"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Master>
```

Observação: Estou escondendo a barra do Navigation, só aparece a barra do MasterDetail mesmo, como na foto abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Feito, se puder dar uma força agradeço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo seu código, na inicialização do app você deve estar fazendo algo assim:

```
App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new FoodSuppy.Principal());
```

E é bem por isso que você precisou 'ocultar a `NavigationBar`'. Eu acho que esse não é bem o cenário para o qual a `MasterDetailPage` foi projetada. As *`CNTP`* exigiriam uma inicializa do app assim:

```
App.Current.MainPage = new FoodSuppy.Principal();
```

[Segundo a documentação](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.MasterDetailPage/),

> *Developers should only use master detail pages as root page.*

Ou seja (em uma tradução livre):

> MasterDetailPage só deve ser usada como página raíz

No seu caso, você poderia colocar uma `NavigationPage` fixa como `Detail` (não precisaria ocultar barra de navegação, a masterdetail já lida com isso) e navegaria a partir dela, se assim preferir.

Poderia ficar assim:

```
<MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <!-- Sua master -->
</MasterDetailPage.Master>
<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage>
        <x:Arguments>
            <!-- a página inicial do `Detail` viria aqui --/>
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

E quando for navegar para uma outra página, seria algo como isso (C#):

```
var principal =  App.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage;
var emExibicao = (principal?.Detail as NavigationPage);
emExibicao?.PushAsync(new OutraPaginaQualquer());
```

O título que será exibido na principal, sempre será o título definido na **página de detalhe** que estiver em exibição.

O que você tem é o modelo de uso comum desse tipo de página: a página contenedora (A instância de `MasterDetailPage`); um `Menu` (que é definido como `Master`) e a página em exibição (que será o `Detail`). Então, basta setar o título que você quiser na página que vai aparecer no detail e tudo certo.

Se a página detail estivesse declarada no `XAML` seria algo assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
              x:Class="FoodSuppy.Principal"
              xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FoodSuppy;assembly=FoodSuppy"> 

    <!-- conteúdo anterior da sua página -->

    <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <ContentPage Title="Tela Principal">
            <Label Text="Pag Principal"/>
            <!-- Conteúdo da página-->
        </ContentPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

A página do tipo `MasterDetailPage` realmente tem algumas particularidades. [No fórum do Xamarin.com tem um comentário de um dos desenvolvedores da equipe Xamarin que esclarece um pouco as coisas.](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/65522/#Comment_65522)